# Displaying Posts by tag dynamically in Wordpress

Tags: tags

How do I come about to display posts related to a random tag? When I click a tag and directed to tag.php page I want all posts related to the previously clicked tag to be displayed. I have seen a lot of example like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag' => 'travel' //how to give a dynamic value
);
```

but I would want 'tag' to be assign dynamically as to whatever tag I click.

Comment: By default, your link would looks like this ``www.domain.com/tag/test2/`` as the tag would be ``test2``. The dynamic parameter is set with the data in the URL. The question is relatively unclear. Do you want to create a script that shows posts based on a random tag in all available tags from the website?

Comment: yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag.php template shouldn't use a custom query for its posts at all. When you visit the link to a tag the main query is automatically populated with posts that have that tag. In the template you output the main query with [the standard loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        ... Display post content
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm sure you know it, but... you don't need `if` statement, if there is no else in it in this case :)

Comment: I just copied the first example from the docs :)